# AVAudioSession - Seems to Think I'm Always Playing Audio

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm using background audio in my iOS app. When the app launches there is no audio playing, but the status bar shows the play icon & the pause button is shown on the remote control. The app seems to think I'm already playing audio.

`viewDidLoad`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

`viewWillAppear`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

**Any ideas why iOS thinks I'm playing audio? How can I fix this?**

I'm receiving the remote events with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I'm using the Finch iOS audio library & part of its initialization convinces iOS that audio is playing.

```
FIFactory *soundFactory = [[FIFactory alloc] init];
FISoundEngine *engine = [soundFactory buildSoundEngine];
[engine activateAudioSessionWithCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback];
[engine openAudioDevice];
```

I would like to use Finch & would like to preload my sound effect so it's ready to go. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be possible without the play icon showing up.